Argo Rollout Trigger is not registered
I have this Argo rollout notification defined:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argo-rollouts-notification-configmap
data:
  template.gitlab-commit-status: |
    webhook:
      mywebhook:
        method: GET
  trigger.on-rollout-completed: |
    - when: rollout.status.conditions[0].reason == 'RolloutCompleted'
      send:
        - gitlab-commit-status

the notification itselfs uses a webhook:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-notifications-cm
data:
  service.webhook.mywebhook: |
    url: XXX
    insecureSkipVerify: true
  subscriptions: |
    - recipients:
        - mywebhook

booth CRDs were installed in my argo-rollout namespace within the cluster.
However when I execute my argo rollout I receive the log message:

error msg="Failed to run trigger, trigger: on-rollout-completed,
destination: {mywebhook }, namespace config:  : trigger
'on-rollout-completed' is not configured"

and

error msg="Notifications failed to send for eventReason
RolloutCompleted with error: [trigger 'on-rollout-completed' is not
configured]" event_reason=RolloutCompleted namespace=team-dev
rollout=guestbook

I followed the common tutorial and I dont see the missing part.
